# Cant list blobs from Synapse notebook

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I am having a bit of a trouble with Synapse notebooks. I want to get a list of blob via pyspark script to dynamically decide which files I want to integrate.
I cannot make this thing work in Synapse.. in other environment such as Jupyter notebook the code is working as expected.

from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient, BlobServiceClient,AccountSasPermissions, ResourceTypes
from azure.storage.blob._shared_access_signature import SharedAccessSignature,BlobSharedAccessSignature

sas_token = 'hardcoded_value'

account_url1 = 'https://*storage_account*.blob.core.windows.net/*container*' + sas_token

print(account_url1)
container_client = ContainerClient.from_container_url(container_url=account_url1)
source_blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in source_blob_list:
print (blob.name + '\n')

The output from the code above in Synapse is:

**ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f282242e130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known**

The output from the code above in Jupyter notebook is as expected..

[snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRo4f.png)

I have  Storage Blob Data Contributor assigned to my user and to Synapse user as well.

Comment: Is the storage Blob Storage or ADLS? For ADLS, we use the abfss URL to navigate the folders/files: rootPath = "abfss://{}@{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(container,account)". If it is Blob Storage, you could try the wasbs format.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to use that format

Answer (score 0):

The above error mainly happens because of invalid syntax of URL.

Please follow below syntax. You will get list of blob files:

```
mssparkutils.fs.ls('wasbs://<container_name>@<Storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/')
```

[image: Ref1]

For more information **refer** this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-file-mount-api)

Answer (score 0):

In the end was permissions to the managed identity of Synapse... The code above was working as I stated outside of Synapse. Now when We added permissions to the managed private endpoint of Synapse everything is working. Thank you!